# Delete AAD Tenant, orphaned Managed Identity

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-managed-identity

I'm attempting to delete an AAD tenant. It fails because there are two Managed Identities still configured. But I can't delete them due to insufficient rights. There is no Azure Subscription attached to the AAD tenant and the Managed Identities don't list a Azure resource ID. Also, there are no applications registered in the AAD tenant.

Comment: We can't check the status of your AAD tenant. Contacting Azure support should be your first choice.

Comment: Are you the global admin of the tenant?

Answer (score 0):

Please ask your Global administrator who will have sufficient rights to remove the managed identities. More details here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-manage-ua-identity-portal

Comment: I am the Global Admin and there are no Azure Subscriptions assigned to the AAD tenant. The only place where I assume I can delete them is in AAD.

Comment: Please share the insufficient rights error message that you are getting so that we can have a look.

Comment: On the properties tab of the Managed Identity I get the banner: 'You can't delete this application because you don't have the right permissions. Learn more.'

Comment: If you are a global admin and still not able to delete the user-assigned managed identities I think reaching out to Azure support will be the next option.

Comment: I don't have a support contract and won't open one just to delete this.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-manage-ua-identity-powershell#delete-a-user-assigned-managed-identity Please try this managed Powershell script to delete user-managed identity

Comment: That is not possible as there are no longer any Azure resources associated with that tenant - hence no possibility to execute cmdlets such as above.